# Conflit between setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: javascript

With an educational purpose I wrote the follow pice of code in JavaScript. The goal is to simulate a teletype machine and after the content is written the machine makes a pause before starts again.

```
var str = 'Some text';
strArray = str.split("");
window.onload = function teleType() {
  var ctrl = 0;
  var wrapId = document.getElementById("wrap");
  var type = setInterval(function() {
    wrapId.innerHTML += strArray[ctrl];
    if (ctrl == strArray.length) {
      wrapId.innerHTML = "";
      ctrl = 0;
      clearInterval(type);
    }
    ctrl++;
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(teleType, 3000);
}
```

But with these intervals (mlliseconds) the machine begin to have an odd behavior. It jumps letters (index) or it starts from the begining without reach the end of the string (array). What is happening between the `setInterval` and the `setTimeout` ?

Comment: did you read how `setInterval` and `setTimeout` works **for educational purpose**?

Comment: @smnbbrv my thought was that in this example the `setTimeout` would only run after the `setInterval` was completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `setInterval` is called you call `setTimeout` immediatelly.
As the result, you will trigger `teleType` before your interval completes.

You can move your `setTimeout` in the end of your interval:

```js
var str = 'Some text';
strArray = str.split("");
window.onload = function teleType() {
  var ctrl = 0;
  var wrapId = document.getElementById("wrap");
  var type = setInterval(function() {
    wrapId.innerHTML += strArray[ctrl];
    if (ctrl == strArray.length) {
      wrapId.innerHTML = "";
      ctrl = 0;
      clearInterval(type);
      setTimeout(teleType, 300);
    }
    ctrl++;
  }, 200);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Now, `teleType` function runs interval, and when it finishes writing text it clears HTML content and tells browser to run `teleType` again in 2 seconds.

By the way, you don't need to set `ctrl` to 0, because it is local and will be reset anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the `setTimeout` would only run after the `setInterval` was completed. For completed I mean when it was clear inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

A sample function which outputs the text to console,

```
function showTeleText(text, repeat) {
    var textByChar = text.split(''),
        intermText = '',
        textPos = 0;

    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        intermText += textByChar[textPos++]
        console.log(intermText);

        if (textPos >= textByChar.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);

            if (repeat) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    showTeleText(text, repeat);
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

on `window.load` call `showTeleText('Some text!', true/false)` like,

```
window.load = function() {
    showTeleText('Some text!', true); 
}
```